# Pi Zero has boot, but doesn't anymore

Tags: pi-zero, boot-issues

So i received my rpi-zero yesterday, it has boot up correctly on the bundled SD Card.
Then, i:

- tried the SD card from a pi3: boot but stayed on the multicolor screen (bad kernel).
- tried a freshly flashed image of raspbian minimal on the bundled SD card: didn't boot (Wrote the image using `dd if=<img> of=/dev/mmcblk0`)

Then saying didn't boot, this mean:

- The activity LED doesn't blink **at all**
- No signal on HDMI port.

Errors i made that could have lead to pi0 damages:

- I plugged the power adapter on the USB OTG port: i read some messages that told that it isn't important and may not have damaged the pi.
- Using my pi3 sdcard (in a quite *unknown* state regarding dtoverlays etc...) while the pi0 had a eInk screen plugged on the GPIO port: could a misconfiguration on dtoverlay + not adapted device on GPIO port could have broke my pi0 ?

Any suggestions to make sure that the pi is died or not is welcome...

Comment: Use something like balena etcher to write and verify a fresh image to the card.  Make sure the power supply is adequate and plugged into the correct microusb slot.

Comment: I try this evening, will keep you informed.

Comment: `dd` implies you used either linux, macOS, or something else which has the potential to read `ext4` filesystems, or at least identify the partitions.  You should be able to check the card that way.

Comment: Ok, so i've been a total nut: just checked the SD card yesterday: it appeared totally blank. After reflashing it, `sync`-ing in Linux (but i supposed it's useless since i believe `sync` works for flushing FS caches) and retrying, my pi0 booted up ! Thanks guy.